# Getting user data after authentication with github in composer rest server

Tags: github-api, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I applied authentication mechanism as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.md) and it works fine but I want to retrieve data of the user after authentication like his username and email how can I do so

Comment: Hi @hosamm-abdallah, how do you finally retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest to read the Github API documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/users/.

Also, this link suggests you can get it from result that comes back from the Github auth provider -> https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server/issues/327#issuecomment-254269482